# setting session variable timeout to unlimited

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

Is it possible to set the timeout of a session variable to say one hour programatically.

How would I go about in doing this?

The reason I am asking is because of storing the contents of an arraylist into a session variable and these contents needs to be available way beyond the current timeout of the session variable.

Comment: Why do you want to keep them in session variable? Is it client specific data? I would suggest you use cache with expiry of 1 hours or whatever time you like.

Comment: @ARS But cache is an application-wide, session unspecific store.

Comment: I use the Session variable to assign the content of an arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the timeout works for the entire session.

But you can set an artificial expiration time for the session item and increase the session max idle time/timeout. Thus you can store an object like this:

```
public class SessionValue 
{
      public object Value { get;set; }
      public DateTimeOffset ExpiresOn { get;set; }
}
```

And whenever you get the whole session item, you can check if it's still valid or it has expired.