# Changing session variables timeout in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an asp.net mvc application in which I am using a `session` attribute:

```
Session["id"] = id;
```

My problem is the timeout of the attribute, I'd like to be unlimited until it changes to another value. Now when the timer expires (30 sec) `Session["id"]` takes `null` as value.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I have been under the impression that the Session timeout can be set, but not an attribute specifically

Comment: You might try to renew the session. Take a look here http://www.primaryobjects.com/2008/01/29/preventing-session-timeouts-in-c-asp-net-web-applications/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default Session Timeout is set to 20 minutes. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> HttpSessionState.Timeout property gets and sets the amount of time, in
>   minutes, allowed between requests before the session-state provider
>   terminates the session.

Keep in mind that **Session is not meant to be Cache**! If you want to be able to define expiration policies on variables, use [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Set the timeout value in [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the web config.
As the comments say this isn't really the best place to put this.

Answer (score 1):

session timeout setting is for the whole session not a specific variable .

I can think of two options :

1- session timeout expiration is sliding . so to prevent it and your session variable from being expired , call session in a period of time e.g each 20 minutes (when session timeout is 30 for example ).

2- better solution is to use cookies , if information are not sensitive .

checking these links may be useful [+](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://forums.asp.net/t/1285066.aspx&ei=qeTKUa76IseB4gSrk4DICA&usg=AFQjCNG32oQDgIqzuMIiTdbW9IT-ANQ0iw&sig2=bLjAqKC1mLKXG0ifB-sBWg&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bGE) , [+](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net&ei=qeTKUa76IseB4gSrk4DICA&usg=AFQjCNF90_gaNUfggHn7GSaAnN_qAFZyFg&sig2=-OH9eoI44SLdoarQnYEYTA&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bGE) , [+](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586001/setting-session-variable-timeout-to-unlimited&ei=qeTKUa76IseB4gSrk4DICA&usg=AFQjCNGPf4izTAnawlGtXZTg2tibyEr82w&sig2=J554Iw7JNM3UAdDXjiL0Vg&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bGE) , [+](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9607/Prevent-Session-Timeout-in-ASP-NET&ei=qeTKUa76IseB4gSrk4DICA&usg=AFQjCNEP-FGAH6GHgsfmAomVjac5S0aHIg&sig2=jKEMoLLXiwiNXCFmVu6plg&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bGE)

Comment: those links look suspicious

Comment: the problem with cookies is the browser limits them to a max size of 4kb, which is not a lot if you serialize the data into JSON format.